# AWK interpretation awk -F'AUTO_INCREMENT=' 'NF==1{print "0";next}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I've going through some simple bash scripts at work that someone else wrote month ago and I've found this line:

```
| awk -F'AUTO_INCREMENT=' 'NF==1{print "0";next}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}'
```

Can someone help me to interpret this line in simple words. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you change original question content? It seems you wanted to post an edit to question but along with that you also tried to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'AUTO_INCREMENT=' '     # Set 'AUTO_INCREMENT=' as a field separator
    NF==1 {                   # If number of fields is one i.e. a blank line
      print "0";              # print '0'
      next                    # Go to next record i.e. skip following code  
    }
    {
      sub(/ .*/,"",$2);       # Delete anything after a space in the second field 
      print $2                # Print the second field 
     }'
```

**Example**

Sample inputs

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=3

AUTO_INCREMENT=10 20 30 foo bar
```

Output

```
3
0
10
```